# drupal---how to debug and find the reason?

Tags: php, drupal

my site's drupal version is 6.19 . there are always logs like the following.

the recent log entries shows
"type: page not found
location:http://www.example.com/display.html
referrer:
message:500.shtml
severity: warning
"

the above's log is generated by when an anonymous accessed the url,but the page ( http://www.example.com/display.html ) content is exist and can access by authenticated user .when i clear the cache. the anonymous can access that page. why and how to find out which reason maybe cause this. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by robots accessing your site, or users refreshing the page after they have been logged out.

I really would not worry about these messages in your logs, they can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should review the CHMOD, does drupal has any notice for this ?